# Multiple faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, xpages, jsf-1.2, managed-bean

My scenario is this:

I have a template with some base code for my application. This template has some custom renderers and some beans in the faces-config.xml file.

Then I have my application that inherits the base code from the template and this application has some additional beans. And everytime I refresh from the template I need to manually add the "local" application beans into faces-config.xml.

Is there a way to have multiple faces-config.xml files or is there another way to fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps a VariableResolver, checking whether it resides inside base or child application?

Comment: You can bundle faces-config into JAR together with beans. Unfortunately, I have problem with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604715/faces-config-xml-in-jar-file-behaves-differently-on-two-dominos.

Comment: Which JSF version-impl are you using?

Comment: Well, it's IBM XPages that is what I know based on JSF 1.2

Comment: This sounds like a perfect use case for an OSGi plugin: shared features applied to an application that, in turn, has its own custom behavior. An XSP Library supports multiple faces-config files because there's an explicit method for declaring which files to load. An NSF, on the other hand, assumes it contributes only one of its own.

Comment: No idea what role "xpages" plays here, but this is definitely possible with standard JSF. See also among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277637/jsf-faces-config-xml-with-external-navigation-rules-xml-file/19277793#19277793

Comment: @TimTripcony Probably would be a good idea. but the deployment of the app will be a pain. Want to contain it into a nsf file, if that can't be done. Editing the file will be best.

Comment: Fredrik with OSGi it will be contained into 2 NSF: your app and the update site. It is less painful than it sounds. @TimTripcony move your comment to the answer, its good.

Comment: @stwissel I don't think it's painful but the all admins that needs to deploy this into 100+ servers,will.

Comment: And, Yes @TimTripcony move your comment to an answer.

Comment: Be a nice guy then... provide a script that creates all the replicas of your database on all servers and updates the notes.ini. Use this as starter http://www.wissel.net/blog/downloads/replicateall.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use case for an OSGi plugin: shared features applied to an application that, in turn, has its own custom behavior. An XSP Library supports multiple faces-config files because there's an explicit method for declaring which files to load. An NSF, on the other hand, assumes it contributes only one of its own.